# How to get the hidden field value to be set within a table that uses pagination?

Tags: c#, html-table, repeater

I have a repeater inside an html table that uses pagination.  I want to be able to read the values of the hidden fields within the repeater in the code behind, but only the hidden field values of the table page being viewed on postback seem to be set when I'm in the code behind.  How do I make it so the hidden field values are set for each repeater item regardless of the table page?

HTML:

```
<div id="divTableContainer" runat="server">
    <table id="tblAssessmentExtracts" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Consumer</th>
                <th>Assessment</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptAssessmentExtractQueue" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptAssessmentExtractQueue_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr class="assessment-extract-block">
                        <td><%# Eval("ConsumerName") %>
                        </td>
                        <td><%# Eval("SurveyName") %>
                        </td>
                        <td><%# Eval("CompletionDate") %></td>
                        <td class="buttoncell">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnExportRecord" runat="server" Text="Export" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdAssessmentId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                            <span class="selection"><asp:HiddenField ID="hdAssessmentSelected" runat="server" /></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#tblAssessmentExtracts').DataTable({
                "pageLength": 25,
            });
        });

        function selectBlock(elementIndex, element) {
            var selectedField = $(element).find('.selection input[type="hidden"]');

            if ($(element).hasClass("table-info") === false) {
                $(element).addClass("table-info");
            }

            if (selectedField.length > 0) {
                selectedField.val("true");
            }
        }
        function deselectBlock(elementIndex, element) {
            var selectedField = $(element).find('.selection input[type="hidden"]');

            if ($(element).hasClass("table-info")) {
                $(element).removeClass("table-info");
            }

            if (selectedField.length > 0) {
                selectedField.val("");
            }
        }
        $('.assessment-extract-block').click(function (e) {

            var selectedField = $(this).find('.selection input[type="hidden"]');
            if (selectedField.length > 0) {
                if (selectedField.val() === "true") {
                    deselectBlock(0, $(this));
                } else {
                    selectBlock(0, $(this));
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
```

C#:

```
private IEnumerable<long> getSelectedResponses()
    {
        List<long> assessmentIds = new List<long>();

        foreach (RepeaterItem riAssessment in rptAssessmentExtractQueue.Items)
        {
            HiddenField hdAssessmentSelected = riAssessment.FindControl("hdAssessmentSelected") as HiddenField;
            HiddenField hdAssessmentId = riAssessment.FindControl("hdAssessmentId") as HiddenField;
            bool export = false;
            if (bool.TryParse(hdAssessmentSelected.Value, out export) && export)
            {
                long assessmentId;
                if (long.TryParse(hdAssessmentId.Value, out assessmentId) && assessmentId > 0)
                {
                    assessmentIds.Add(assessmentId);
                }
            }
        }

        return assessmentIds;
    }
```